# Can a VS Code theme customize the color of tokens in a way that is more specific than defined by language-support-extension-contributed token scopes?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes, token

Is there a way in a VS Code theme to specifically color a targeted class? For example, if I wanted (in JS) to target the console class and color the word "console" a particular color any time it is referenced, is there a way to do that? Currently in the theme I have done some semantic highlighting, but I want to do some more specific highlighting for certain things.

So far I have looked at token scopes but I have not found any specific enough for the case I am describing.

Comment: use the extension Highlight

Comment: @rioV8 - I am looking for a solution that I can actually put into my theme.json file for my color theme. I want it to be part of the color scheme so that it comes out-of-the-box that way when people download the theme. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: if the TextMate Grammar of the language does not assign a special scope to your special words you are out of luck, use the TextMate Scope inspector if that is the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, at the time of this writing, no, and I'd wager that this is unlikely to be supported in the future. What you get from the TextMate token scopes / semantic tokens contributed by language support extensions is what you get.

You can look into extensions that allow you to define your own patterns for colourization on top of the builtin syntax highlighting mechanisms, but those are not a themable thing in the sense of being something you can control with a theme.json. One such extension is [`fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight) <sup><sub>I have no affiliation with this extension</sub></sup>.