# coloring log statements in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, logging, colors, focus

I'm wondering if I can **change the color of my log statements** in my code. anyway to do it?
I want them **dimmer (kinda like comments)** so that it won't be as distracting and I can focus more on my actual codes. I'm thinking somthing like how "better comments" extension works.

i.e: when I enter a keyword/symbol like: #^ <<<<<< LOG >>>>>> the next line becomes dimmer.

[image]

I can change the color of comments using "better comments" but I want to change the color of any arbitrary lines of code.

by the way I can do this using #region and #endregion:

[image]

but I prefer somthing more refined if possible.

Comment: perhaps see https://stackoverflow.com/q/76949403/11107541

Comment: thanks @starball . That wasn't exactly what I wanted, but I did something which is not bad as a workaround. I'll post it as a possible answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work around it using "better comments".

```json
        {
            "tag": "region#",
            "color": "#565185",
            "strikethrough": false,
            "underline": false,
            "backgroundColor": "transparent",
            "bold": false,
            "italic": true
        },
        {
            "tag": "endregion#",
            "color": "#565185",
            "strikethrough": false,
            "underline": false,
            "backgroundColor": "transparent",
            "bold": false,
            "italic": true
        }
```

with this, I can fold my logging blocks and the color is dark enough, so it won't be as distracting as before.

here's a screenshot: (both folded and expanded views)

[image]