# Visual studio code style custom tag

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do i style a custom tag in visual studio code. For example how do I style this code:

[image]

---

I tried to make some changes to the textMateRules of my settings.json file, but I encountered several problems:

1. I cannot target a specific tag for styling. In the scope of the
   `textMateRule`, I used `meta.tag.other.unrecognized.html.derivative` to
   target the `<e /e>` tag, but it is not specific to this tag. It is
   also not an HTML tag but a custom server side scripting tag.
2. This tag should always be styledas defined in the rule. If
   this tag is nested in another tag, it should still be styled. In
   other words, it supersedes all other styling rules.
3. The tag is defined by a specific sequence of characters. In my
   case, it is opened by `<e` and closed by `/e>`. Now the tag is closed whenever it encouters a `>` charater. E.g.

[image]

---

My current settings.json file looks like this:

```
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": [
                "meta.tag.other.unrecognized.html.derivative entity.name.tag.html",
                "meta.tag.other.unrecognized.html.derivative entity.other.attribute-name.html",
                "meta.tag.other.unrecognized.html.derivative invalid.illegal.character-not-allowed-here.html",
                "meta.tag.other.unrecognized.html.derivative string.unquoted.html",
                "meta.tag.other.unrecognized.html.derivative punctuation.separator.key-value.html",
                "text.html.derivative invalid.illegal.bad-angle-bracket.html",
                "meta.tag.custom.start.html entity.name.tag.html",
                "meta.attribute.unrecognized.include(.html entity.other.attribute-name.html",
                "meta.tag.custom.start.html punctuation.definition.tag.end.html"                

            ],
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#d413b4",
                "fontStyle": "italic"
             }                  
            

        }
        ....
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76949403/11107541

Comment: Please add the rules (the `textMateRule`) that you created, even if they do not do what you want them to do.

Comment: I had another look at this, but all the code (HTML?)samples you provide are not valid HTML, and, my guess is, that this will cause `TextMateRules` to fail.

Comment: @Luuk It is not HTML, it is a server side rendering tag.  Like php's <?php ?> tag.

Comment: Either: [Embedded languages](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#embedded-languages) or [Developing a new grammar extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#developing-a-new-grammar-extension) seem to apply ?  (from the [Syntax Highlight Guide of Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide)