# How to only modify one keyword color in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, colors, customization

I've been modying my setting.json (probably in a Sort of inefficient way), but I got it to have most of the colors exactly how I want them, the only problem that i'm having Is that i'm using "entity.name.function.preprocessor" to edit the colors of "true", "false" and "NULL", but that also changes the color of "bool". Is there a way to change the color of "bool" and keeping the same color for the other words? Or viceversa?

I haven't tried much, I asked both chatgpt and github copilot but they both gave me answers that didn't work. Unfortunately i'm writing this on my phone and the code is on my PC. If anyone needs it, i'll try to get it

Comment: what programming language is this for? C? this might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/76949403/11107541

Comment: if they have the exact same TextMate Scope you can't customize it, You might have a look at Highlight extension